# How do I stop receiving: TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.7.0, and I keep getting TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined. Can someone please tell me what the problem is? My jQuery is below. Thank you.

```
    function removeNewItem() {
        $('.aboutitemdelete').unbind('click');

        $('.aboutitemdelete').on('click', function () {

            // Get Related Object
            var current = $(this).attr('rel').replace('aboutitemremove_', '');

            // Removing Element
            $('#aboutitem_' + current).remove();

            //Assign Current Element Count
            answercount = parseInt($('#answercount').val());
            answercount -= (answercount > 1) ? 1 : 0;
            $('#answercount').val(answercount);
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button_admin_newitem').on('click', function () {

            alert('a');

            current = $('.aboutsectionitem:last').attr('id').replace('aboutitem_', '');
            current = Number(++current);

            alert('b');

            $('div.aboutitemsholder').append('<div id="aboutitem_' + current + '" class="aboutsectionitem"><h4 class="titlebar_span">About Page Item</h4><div class="aboutrow_sep"><label>Section Label</label><input id="seclabel_' + current + '" type="text" class="text" /><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="aboutrow_sep"><label>Section Content</label><div class="aboutrow_editor_holder">Telerik Editor Goes Here<div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="aboutrow_sep"><label>Enabled?</label><input id="itemenable_' + current + '" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="aboutrow_sep"><label>Sort Order</label><input id="sortitem_' + current + '" type="text" class="text" style="max-width: 50px;" /><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="aboutitemremove"><label>Delete</label><a href="#" class="aboutitemdelete" rel="aboutitemremove_' + current + '"><span>Remove</span></a></div></div>');

            answercount = parseInt($('#answercount').val()) + 1;
            $('#answercount').val(answercount);

            removeNewItem();

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What line are you getting this on?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: Maybe the some item upon the `attr` method is called dont have a `rel` attribute and the `replace` throw the error since it don't have an input value to operate upon?

Comment: I think diosney may be right: http://jsfiddle.net/3bJHj/

Comment: eh.. but the error that shows is - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined` not `TypeError: $(…).attr(…) is undefined`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ `"$(…).attr(…)" is undefined` leads me to believe that .attr is in fact returning undefined.

Comment: the better guess would be that `$('.aboutsectionitem:last')` <-- isn't returning an element

Comment: No, because that not returning an element will still have a .attr method.

Comment: hmm.. maybe dunno.. don't have enough info to test it out

Comment: Although, its still a possibility, $().attr("rel") will also return undefined because no elements are selected.

Comment: @KevinB ah you are correct about that - just tested it out

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. Kevin B was right on the money.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> > As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.

My guess is the attribute you are searching for isn't set on the element you're searching for it on. Due to this, .replace is failing because undefined doesn't have a replace method. You'll need to make sure it isn't undefined first.

```
var current = $(this).attr('rel');
current = current ? current.replace('aboutitemremove_', '') : '';
```

do this for the id in the next area too.