# TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.weight').live('input',function() {
        var t = $(this).attr('id').replace('weight-',''); 

        var table_name = $('#table_name-'+t+' option:selected').val();

        var quality_color_value = parseFloat($('#quality-color-'+t+' option:selected').attr('data-id').split('\`')[0]);

        var diamond_weight = parseFloat($('#quality-color-'+t+' option:selected').attr('data-id').split('\`')[1]);

        var diamond_pcs = parseFloat($('#diamond-pcs-'+t).val()); 

        if(table_name == 1){ 
           var diamond_weight = parseFloat($('#weight-'+t).val()); 
        }

        if(table_name == 2){
            $('#weight-'+t).val(diamond_weight);
        } 

    });
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you if you haven't even asked a question?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the posted duplicate link:

> http://api.jquery.com/attr/
>
> > As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.
>
> My guess is the attribute you are searching for isn't set on the
>   element you're searching for it on. Due to this, .replace is failing
>   because undefined doesn't have a replace method. You'll need to make
>   sure it isn't undefined first.
>
> ```
> var current = $(this).attr('rel');
> current = current ? current.replace('aboutitemremove_', '') : "";
> ```
>
> do this for the id in the next area too.

[How do I stop receiving: TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240135/how-do-i-stop-receiving-typeerror-attr-is-undefined)

Comment: Please don't copy the content of other answers, especially not if the question is already voted closed on as duplicate.